# TurboMail 3 with Pylons 1.0 - MailNotEnabledException

Tags: python, pylons

I am trying to setup TurboMail 3 with Pylons 1.0

Followed the [docs here](http://packages.python.org/TurboMail/chapters/detailed.html#pylons)

I have added this to the development.ini

```
[DEFAULT]
...
mail.on = true
mail.manager = immediate 
mail.transport = smtp 
mail.smtp.server = localhost
```

and my app_globals.py looks like:

```
"""The application's Globals object"""

from beaker.cache import CacheManager
from beaker.util import parse_cache_config_options

class Globals(object):

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.cache = CacheManager(**parse_cache_config_options(config))

     from turbomail.adapters import tm_pylons
     tm_pylons.start_extension()
```

My controller has this method:

```
def submit(self):
    message = Message("from@example.com", "to@example.com", "Hello World")
    message.plain = "TurboMail is really easy to use."
    message.send()
```

The problem is that I am getting this error when message.send() is been called:

```
MailNotEnabledException: An attempt was made to use a facility of the TurboMail framework but outbound mail hasn't been enabled in the config file [via mail.on]
```

I don't know what am I missing here? 
It all seems right according to the docs!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pylons 1.0 made several backwards-incompatible changes to how (and when) the configuration is stored in a global object.  In this case, the configuration is no longer loaded when the Globals object is instantiated.  Instead, you will have to change your code to the following:

```
import atexit
from turbomail import interface
from turbomail.adapters import tm_pylons
from beaker.cache import CacheManager
from beaker.util import parse_cache_config_options

class Globals(object):
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.cache = CacheManager(**parse_cache_config_options(config))

        atexit.register(tm_pylons.shutdown_extension)
        interface.start(tm_pylons.FakeConfigObj(config))
```

The above (atexit and interface.start) is exactly what the start_extension() code does.

I'll be releasing an updated TurboMail to allow passing the configuration as an argument to start_extension(), which should clear this up in a more sane way.